# problem with lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, colorbox

I am having problem with making my thumbnails as lightbox.

Link: http://www.ceanagupta.com/

The images are loaded off Flickr. After load, I want to implement the lightbox, but I am getting JavaScript error:

> jQuery(".picasaGalleryItem").colorbox is not a function

Maybe this is something basic, and I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nasty solution is to replace:

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery(".picasaGalleryItem").colorbox();
    },2000);
```

with

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var _colorbox = $.colorbox;     

        setTimeout(function(){
            _colorbox.apply($('.picasaGalleryItem'));   
        }, 2000);
    });
```

But seriously... don't unclude jquery twice

Comment: Thanks, the problem isnt with timeout, it was only because of the twice jquery load.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the ColorBox [FAQ](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/#jquery). If I look at the requests I see `jquery.min.js` twice.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the problem, and I have been looking all around. There was one more instance of jQuery being loaded from within the script.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you should wrap your jQuery code in $(document).ready like so (the DOM is not guaranteed ready at the time of execution):

```
$(function() { //CODE HERE });
```

Second, you will need to make sure that the images and containing `<div>` are loaded before you actually execute colorbox on those DIVs. Since you are loading the image gallery asynchronously, you will need to implement a callback function that executes after the images are loaded, with the colorbox function inside. As far as I can tell, you will need to implement this inside of your picasa.js file.

Comment: indeed, i implemented that. helped in instant execution